# unittest class not able to import source module in python

Tags: python, flask

Below is my directory structure:

```
projectFolder
  src
    __init__.py
    controller
      __init.py
      moduleA.py
  test
    __init__.py
    test_moduleA.py
```

Below is my import statement in test_module,py

```
import src.controller.moduleA as moda
```

Comment: How do you launch your tests? Do you launch them from a project root folder (i.e. projectFolder)?

Comment: I launch my test in eclipse. I directly run the class in unittest mode in eclipse.

Comment: Well, most likely there is a problem with a working directory when you launch your tests, because import statement is relative to working dir. You can check it by adding `import os; print(os.getcwd())` as a first line in test_module.py. If it's not the `projectFolder`, then that may be the problem.